# Rails 4 - select related records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On my application, I have an object for many-to-many relationships called "selection"

```
class Selection < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :projecttype
end
```

and 2 objects to relate to each other

```
class Projecttype < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :selections
has_many :questions, :through => :selections
validates :projecttype, uniqueness: true, length: { is: 3 }
validates :name, presence: true
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

And...

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :selections
has_many :projecttypes, :through => :selections
validates :question, presence: true
validates :comment, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5}
validates :sequence, presence: true
end
```

Now in my edit form for the projecttype, I want to be able to select related questions (using check boxes).

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><%= f.label :selection %></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><%= f.select :selection, {}, {:multiple => true, :style => "width:100%; border:none" } %></div>
    </div>
```

Have tried options_for_selection and _from_collection and don't anymore know what to do as I get many errors.

what should the `f.select` code be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little rusty with Rails now, but it should be something like this.

`<%= f.select :selection, Selection.all.collect {|x| x.name}, {}, :multiple => true %>`

and don't forget to add

`def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, category_ids: [])
end`

to your selection.rb file

Comment: what is the post params in de selection.rb doing in this case (they are not used in the f.select)?  Meanwhile, without the post_partams, tried this and the view renders error free, yet no items are listen

Comment: html generate is <select include_blank="None" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%;" name="projecttype[selections][]" id="projecttype_selections"></select>